# How to filter the files which's name is not end with "d.lib" on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

There are some files which are named `xxxx.lib` or `xxxxd.lib`. I want to search for files ending in `xxxxd.lib` and files ending in `xxxx.lib`

I tried to filter them out by using a .bat file.
Here is my code, and the last command does not work:

```bat
@echo off
for %%I in (*.lib) do echo %%I>>all.txt
for %%I in (*d.lib) do echo %%I>>adebug.txt
for %%I in (*.lib) do if "%%~nI"!= (*d.lib) echo %%I>>arelease.txt
```

Comment: [Windows cmd and DOS are completely different things](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter use [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) with the `/E` option to match at the end and `/V` to print lines that don't match that suffix. And you don't need a `for` loop in this case, just use `dir /b`

```
dir /b *.lib >>all.txt
dir /b *d.lib >>adebug.txt
dir /b *.lib | findstr /V /E "d.lib" >>arelease.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! But it still out put "xxxd.lib" and "xxx.lib" in arelease.txt. such as "pcl_common.lib
pcl_commond.lib"

Comment: I slove it!!!!! `dir /b *.lib | findstr /V /E d.lib >>arelease.txt` is right , just need to remove the '*' in "*.lib". Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of one way of performing the requested task from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), without making assumptions or simply getting lucky.

```sh
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& "%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe"
 ".":"*.lib" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /R /I /C:"d.lib$"'
) Do @(Echo %%~nxG) 1>>"arelease.txt"
```

If you want it as a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```sh
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& "%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe" ".":"*.lib" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /R /I /C:"d.lib$"') Do @(Echo %%~nxG) 1>>"arelease.txt"
```

Or from the Command Prompt, [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Set "PATHEXT=" ^& "%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe" ".":"*.lib" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /R /I /C:"d.lib$"') Do @(Echo %~nxG) 1>>"arelease.txt"
```

In all cases above, you can change `%~nxG` to `%~G`, if you'd prefer to include the full paths, as opposed to just their filenames.